# Inline assembly gets segmentation fault(core dump)

Tags: c

I'm trying to use "int $0x1a" to have bios call, to search PCI device in Linux. It's implemented in C language with inline assembly. The code shows below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int findpci(int device_id, int plx_id){
  int result;
  __asm__(
      "pushl %%eax \n\t"
      "pushl %%ebx \n\t"
      "pushl %%ecx \n\t"
      "pushl %%edx \n\t"
      "pushl %%esi \n\t"
      "movl $0xb102, %%eax \n\t"
      "movl %2, %%ecx \n\t"
      "movl %3, %%edx \n\t"
      "movl $0x0000, %%esi \n\t"
      "int  $0x1a \n\t"
      "movl %%ebx, %0 \n\t" 
      "movb %%ah, %1 \n\t"
      "popl %%esi \n\t"
      "popl %%edx \n\t"
      "popl %%ecx \n\t"
      "popl %%ebx \n\t"
      "popl %%eax \n\t"
      :"=r"(result), "=r"(flag)
      :"r"(device_id), "r"(plx_id)
      );
    return result;
}
int main(){
  int c = findpci(0x9050, 0x10B5);
  printf("%d\n", c);  
  return 0;
}
```

But I got "segmentation fault(core dump)". What's wrong with my code. Is that it could not call "int $0x1a" in the system?

Comment: Can you tell where the error occurred?

Comment: This is most probably an arror with ASM code, not really c language, you should add better tags to your question.

Comment: You're right, it's not possible to do BIOS calls from Linux programs. Look at the "lspci" program instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that it could not call "int $0x1a" in the system?

Yes, it's not possible to do BIOS calls from Linux programs. I suggest you look at the `lspci` program instead.

Comment: Is that linux close bios interrupt, while DOS does not close? Can DOS system call "int $0x1a"?

Comment: It's because the BIOS is replaced by the operating system. BIOS calls like this will work in DOS and very old versions of Windows, but in all newer operating systems, there will be other system calls that achieve the same thing, and you should use those instead. I don't know how to scan the PCI bus in Linux, but if you look at the `lspci` source code, you will find the answer.

Comment: Okay,thank you very much! I just hate writing assembly language, and want to find a easy way to finish my homework.